# Saving and retrieving state in web forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a 'work book' ruby on rails application. Basically a user will read a paragraph or two and then answer some questions based on what they've read.

I'm unsure how to model this. The paper work books have many pages and each page has many paragraphs.
Should I model it exactly as it is in physical form or should I simplify the model?

My biggest question is how do I save state so that a user can update their workbook and or make corrections after they've submitted part of their assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these relations could work for you:

```
class WorkBook
  has_many :pages

class Page
  belongs_to :work_book
  has_many :paragraphs

class Paragraph
  belongs_to :page
  has_many :questions

class Question
  belongs_to :paragraph
  has_many :answers

class Answer
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user

class User
  has_many :answers
  has_many :answered_questions, class_name: 'Question', through: :answers
```

If you want a better control on your answers (like value_string, value_float, value_boolean, etc.) I recommend you to add an extra model "AnswerValue".

You might feel like there is too much models in this case, but trust me, it makes your app flexible and allows you to add more "granular" features on each model / relation.

**An extenstion with these relations:** You could add a model "AnswerCorrection" which would act like an Answer but would be a way to save another value after the user update it's workbook.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Beat me to the post button - this is what I would recommend as well, almost exactly the same as my response

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for something like this:

```
class PaperWork < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pages
  has_many :paragraphs, through: :pages
end

class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :paper_work
  has_many :paragraphs
end

class Paragraph
  belongs_to :page
  belongs_to :paper_work, through: :page
end
```

Then you can model assignments somewhat around this idea:

```
class Asignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :paragraph
  # attributes: description, status(pending, completed, etc.)
end
```